# Using Python or C behind a grails application

Tags: python, grails, groovy, jms, activemq-classic

I'm working on a grails app that deals with a lot of image processing. The workflow is:

- user uploads an image
- item is added to the queue
- backend process would pick item from the queue and perform analysis on it

I came across OpenCV which has a lot of functions I would like to use, however, the java wrapper for it [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) is a pain to work with. It lacks documentation other than few examples in Java/Scala. However, it has decent documentation for C or [Python](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/).

So I'm wondering whether it is OK to write queue workers in Python or C. The workers would pick-up an item from the queue, process it, and put it back in the queue so that my grails application can pick it up.

My questions are:

- What should I use for my queue? JMS Plugin?
- Is there anything special I need to do to have Python or C recognize that there is a new item in the queue? Is this something that ActiveMQ is good for?
- Do you see major problems with my approach?
- Any links showing this type of cross-platform demonstration with JMS would be appreciated

Comment: from 2.4.4 on, opencv comes with own java bindings, have a look at those

Comment: We are more or less doing the same thing and are using RabbitMQ (AMQP) and ImageMagick for image handling. It works like a charm. All is handled in 2 Grails project: one for uploading etc and the other contains the workers. We have split these up but you can also combine them in 1 project. Grails RabbitMQ plugin is doing the messaging stuff for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What should I use for my queue? JMS Plugin?

I guess you can run into the same problem with different queue implementations: you may not find a good C or Python API for a JMS.

Why not just use a database table as queue?

- Is there anything special I need to do to have Python or C recognize that there is a new item in the queue? Is this something that ActiveMQ is good for?

Nothing special - you jsut have to know how to work with a queue... :-) ActiveMQ is a well known JMS implementation in the Java-World

- Do you see major problems with my approach?

Not if you can handle two different languages in your project. This will add complexity. And if you decide to use a JMS solution, you will also add complexity through the Queue-Manager...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With grails 2, you can using Python code via Jython,
And in Grails 3+, spring boot make using Python far more easier than grails2.

Here is some info:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-python/1.2.x/sphinx/html/